# Problem on Convergence of random series

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, examples-counterexamples

Suppose that $\{X_n\}$ is an independent sequence and $E[X_n]=0$. If $\sum \operatorname{Var}[X_n] < \infty$, then $\sum X_n$ converges with probability $1$. Is independence necessary condition here ? I am thinking of a counterexample. The intuition behind the other assumptions is clear.

Answer (score 0):

It is. Let $X_1$ be $1$ or $-1$ with probabilities $1/2$ and let $X_n := \frac{1}{n} X_1$. series of variances is convergent, while $\sum X_n$ doesn't.

Comment: Your series actually does converge to $X_1$.

Comment: no, it doesn't. the sum is never even defined, it's either $\infty$ or $-\infty$ as $\sum_1^N X_n = (\sum_1^N \frac{1}{n}) X_1$ (you have typos in your example tho)

Comment: Which equals x1.

Comment: no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The condition can be relaxed, but not removed.  Take for instance the following example:

$$X_n = \frac{Z}{\sqrt{n}},$$

where $Z\sim N(0,1)$.  Then $E(X_n)=0$ and

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty V(X_n) = 1,$$

but

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n= \sqrt{n} Z$$

diverges.

Comment: The variance of $X_n$ is $1/n$, the series diverges. The formula for the sum of $X_n$ is also wrong. Given that you could not understand the *correct* example by mm-aops, hardly surprising.